# What is the aspect ratio of a keel and how does it affect your how your boat sails?

Tags: sailing

I have heard of aspects of sails and keels, and it seems that taller skinnier sails and keels have this *higher aspect ratio*. What is it and what does it do for your sailing?

Comment: ["Aspect ratio" is essentially the ratio of width to height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forces_on_sails#Aspect_ratio) - so "A high aspect ratio indicates a long, narrow sail, whereas a low aspect ratio indicates a short, wide sail". Keel is probably similar.

Comment: @DJClayworth would you like to convert this to an answer?

Comment: Not really because I know nothing about how it affects sailing. However if you're only looking for a definition I could.

Answer (score 6):

Aspect ratio describes the ratio between sail/keel height divided by (average) width. So a high aspect ratio is tall and skinny and a low aspect ratio is short and fat.

For sails one of the main affects of aspect ratio is on drag. High aspect ratio tend to produce [lower drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forces_on_sails#Aspect_ratio) (i.e. more powerful) sails for the same area. Therefore, modern racing boats tend to have fairly square sail designs (higher aspect ratio) see picture. Another minor advantage of high aspect ratio sails is for inland sailing where wind is often obscured. In this case higher aspect ratios are more likely to get clean air than a shorter sail, see [Thames A raters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thames_A-class_rater).
On the other hand higher aspect ratio gives greater truning motion and so requires a bigger keel/is more likely to capsize.

For keels the greater righting motion of high aspect ratios is one of the main advantages. Additionally, high aspect ratio keels are easier to turn although there will be some loss of sideways resistance from the decreased width.

[image]

Comment: Also using a longer keel allows more of its length to be in 'stable' water underneath the turbulent surface layer. This reduces drag losses.

Comment: "modern racing boats tend to have fairly square sail designs (higher aspect ratio)". Square sails have lower aspect ratio, as you say elsewhere. I believe other factors are involved in the squareness of racing sails.

Comment: When you say square, do you mean rectangular in the sense of squarer corners, less square in the sense of the height being at a higher ratio to the width?

Answer (score 0):

The keel does two 'things' ... 'slice' ...it keeps the boat from turning when on a tack, in fact it is the reason you can tack at all. The other purpose is to offset the forces applied on the boat by the sails by leveraging the ballast against them. a skinny keel with a huge mass at the end will provide a better mechanical advantage. a long and deep keel will give you the best forward 'slice'.

Comment: That's actually kinda backward. A full keel will prevent turning better than a fin keel will which has a tendency to dance atop waves. However a fin keel is supposed to have a higher aspect ratio which allows better pointing into the wind, but I don't understand why.

Comment: but I don't understand why... that is very clear and  then you should not be commenting and criticizing someone with 50 years exp and 35,000 miles of blue water experience

Comment: Hehe, ok full disclosure. I posed the question to get some sailing content going was hoping for a good answer that I didn't provide myself. I know full well how aspect works. I also happen to have a lot of experience on the water and I am sitting for my Masters exam on Wednesday. A full keel tracks much better, but it's drags to the side when trying to point. A fin keel with high aspect sails points really high to the wind, but when it comes to rough seas, it's much tougher to hold your heading, because there isn't much keeping you from spinning around the keel, especially atop a big wave.

Comment: OK got it I would like to get the same going here as well. the postings here are clearly from those who are going to get hurt sailing and that is sooo wrong. the problem with this site is requires a question to be asked and then an answer randomly answered ... and mostly by people that have seen a video and do not understand the kinematics of sailing.  GOOD LUCK ON YOUR EXAM!!!! fyi I'm rated at 100 tons and have sailed the Mystic Whaler.

Comment: I know the mystic whaler very well. And after next week I will also be 100 GRT (well I still have to file the paperwork). So the question I have next is, are you still around this area and if so can we go have a beer?

Comment: Sure man .. I am in the Chesapeake on the Choptank. I live on the water in Cambridge with my 1968 28' cal jensen flattop I restored as well as a cape fear 39, and person 39, and a morgan 46 in restoration. I am part of the Schooner group with 'Prom Queen' a French aluminum hull Chantal Whitbread racer. the mystic comes down every year and we all race around the keg for the weekend.

Comment: Ah ok, I live near her home port. So that's a little far for a beer. I assumed you lived in this area since you mentioned her. I do a bit of etchells racing with my brother in law in the summer, but haven't done any windjammer racing. I am however building a 65ft wooden schooner (GRP over 2 in of plywood 4x 1/2 inch plies) at the moment. Hope to have her done in about 3 years.

Comment: Awsome!!! hey I refit my person and cal with hydraulic drives. basically a distributed system of power transfer. as a systems engineer for Westinghouse you can imagine that I have it all electronic controlled. I have every control for the engine in the call mounted on the tiller . no levers or switches to bang you knees on in the cockpit. and I have the entire navigation and RADAR using less than 12 watts. I use sunlight readable displays eink.com for the maps  which are NOAA maps not garmin or the like .. less than a grand.